# Add/Remove 'attributes' based on Angular variables or evaluated expressions in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i know ng-class can add/remove 'classes' based on Angular variables
or based on evaluated expressions. But if i want to say put an attribute like 'readonly' on an element based some variable in the controller, what is the simplest method. I wish a directive like 'ng-attr' exists.

Answer (score 2):

for `readonly` you can use `ngReadonly`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

for more general solution check `ngAttr`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation